# How to block routes with '/' on create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'm creating a simply SPA with four pages and I found one big issue that crashes my app. I have four routes:

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact path='/przewodnictwo' component={Conductivity} />
     <Route exact path='/apartamenty' component={Apartments} />
     <Route exact path='/przewoz_osob' component={Transport} />
     <Route exact path='/narciarstwo' component={Skiing} />
     <Redirect from='*' to='/przewodnictwo' />
</Switch>
```

Everything works perfekt and my NavLinks looks like this:

```
<NavLink exact to='/apartamenty'>
       Apartamenty
</NavLink>
```

All my images are loaded from public folder. Any other routes like `/example`, `/przewodnictwo/23` are redirecting me to main page which is `/przewodnictwo`. But strange things are happening when I write in url `/przewodnictwo/` or `/apartamenty/` these are not blocked and my images are being loaded from not public folder but from `/public/apartamenty/3.jpg` which dosen't exists.

**EDIT**

I forgot to add '/' to paths images and now works perfect. src='1.jpg' has been changed to src='/1.jpg' Thank you for help.

But how to block '/przewodnictwo/' route ?? I really don't like this url, it's ugly

Comment: Can you show the code, where you show/load the pictures?

Comment: Which router are you using?

Comment: @cbdev420 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'; v^4.3.1

Comment: @BorysKupar yes I forgot this, I have added / to paths and works perfect, but still how to block this url: '/przewodnictwo/' ??

Comment: You mean, if someone enters `/przewodnictwo/` you want the result to be not found?

Comment: @cbdev420 yes, but with this routes it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block the trailing slashes from matching your routes, you can use the `strict` prop on the Route component.

**Source: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/strict-bool**

> **`<Route>`**
>
> **strict: bool**
>
> When true, a path that has a trailing slash will only match a location.pathname with a trailing slash. This has no effect when there are additional URL segments in the location.pathname.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you were first so I accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strict` keyword to avoid trailing slash. According to react-router documentation for strict

> When `true`, a path that has a trailing slash will only match a
>   `location.pathname` with a trailing slash. This has no effect when there
>   are additional URL segments in the `location.pathname`.

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact strict path='/przewodnictwo' component={Conductivity} />
     <Route exact strict path='/apartamenty' component={Apartments} />
     <Route exact strict path='/przewoz_osob' component={Transport} />
     <Route exact strict path='/narciarstwo' component={Skiing} />
     <Redirect from='*' to='/przewodnictwo' />
</Switch>
```